# DrRacket Scheme current-pseudo-random-generator contract violation

Tags: scheme, racket

For the following line:

```
(random 9 current-pseudo-random-generator)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
. . random: contract violation
  expected: (or/c (integer-in 1 4294967087) pseudo-random-generator?)
  given: #<procedure:current-pseudo-random-generator>
>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`current-pseudo-random-generator`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=random#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._current-pseudo-random-generator%29%29) is a [parameter](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html?q=random#%28tech._parameter%29), so you must use it like

```
(random 9 (current-pseudo-random-generator))
```

By default, `random` will use that automatically so you could simplify your example to `(random 9)`.